# AttributeError at /api/project/ 'Query' object has no attribute 'query_terms' tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

```
class Project(models.Model):
     project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     intro = models.TextField(default=None)
     start_date = models.DateField()
     end_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
       return self.project_name



class UserResource(ModelResource):
     class Meta:


class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
     user = fields.ToManyField(UserResource, 'user',  full=True)

    class Meta:
       queryset = Project.objects.all()
       resource_name = 'project'
       allowed_methods = ['post', 'get']
       authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

Newbie in tastypie, When i follow the documents i get attribute error on api url (api/project/) dont know the meaning of query_terms, tried searching  , thanks in advance

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 221, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 461, in dispatch_list
    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 493, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 1348, in get_list
    objects = self.obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 2157, in obj_get_list
    applicable_filters = self.build_filters(filters=filters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 2036, in build_filters
    query_terms = self._meta.queryset.query.query_terms
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'query_terms'
```

Comment: What Django and TastyPie versions are you using?

Comment: Hey thanks, I was using wrong versions of tastypie and Django.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the current versions of Django and Tastypie don't go well together.
The fix is hidden in the link given by Nelly Ngo, more specifically [here](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/pull/1520/commits/d5887ba291d976ae29ce9b3fc2ab22094b6344db).

A temporary hackish fix is to patch tastypie/resources.py.
At /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tastypie on my system.

Replace the lines:

```
if getattr(self._meta, 'queryset', None) is not None:
    # Get the possible query terms from the current QuerySet.
    query_terms = self._meta.queryset.query.query_terms
else:
    query_terms = QUERY_TERMS
```

with:

```
query_terms = QUERY_TERMS
```

and

```
query_terms = query_terms | set(GeometryField.class_lookups.keys())
```

with:

```
query_terms |= set(GeometryField.class_lookups.keys())
```